# Problem accessing www.evernote.com with Firefox on Ubuntu

Tags: firefox

About a week ago I found that I could no longer log in to Evernote ([www.evernote.com](http://www.evernote.com)) using Firefox. When I click the LogIn link, I get the message "This page isn't redirectly correctly". This happens on both Ubuntu 20.10 and Ubuntu 21.04. The problem occurs with both Firefox 88.0.1 and Firefox 90.0a1.  I CAN access my Evernote account using Chrome. Also I am able to access my account using Firefox on Windows 10. For some reason Evernote seems to regard the GET as "suspicious" when coming from Ubuntu.

I have tried clearing the cookies without any success.

Anyone have any ideas?  (Both versions of Ubuntu are up to date with patches.) Here follows the wireshark trace of the attempted login.

```
GET /Login.action HTTP/1.1
Host: www.evernote.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:90.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/90.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://evernote.com/
Cookie: web50017PreUserGuid=05e33559-c1c5-4598-acff-161d5974978f
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-GPC: 1

HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: AkamaiGHost
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 2
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Location: /Login.action?err=true&message=login.error.suspicious
Expires: Sat, 15 May 2021 15:12:13 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Sat, 15 May 2021 15:12:13 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Have you compared the preferences on FF for Windows and Linux, particularly in regards to cookies? Also, have you seen this? https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/985967

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is Ubuntu, it may be Firefox 88. I tried to use Evernote authorise for my webapp in development on Mac Pro 10.15.7 and got the [www.evernote.com/Login.action?err=true&message=login.error.suspicious](http://www.evernote.com/Login.action?err=true&message=login.error.suspicious)

I get the same response just using https://www.evernote.com

Cookies are set to allow for the domain.

(This will be irritating as I've only just finished the feature)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your question - just a comment: I access Evernote (constantly, every day) using Firefox 88.0.1 on Pop!_OS 20.04 and have not experienced any trouble at all.  I have a premium account with Evernote - I don't know whether that would make any difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

[Resolved]

I'm still not sure what the problem was but it was "cured" by rebooting the system. My apologies for posting before doing that.